# submitting a multiple values and hidden values on checkbox in html

Tags: java, html, jsp, checkbox

Is there a way to submit multiple form fields by tying it to one checkbox
eg:

`<input type=hidden name=code value="cycle_code" />`

`<input type=checkbox name=vehicle value="cycle" />`

`<input type=hidden name=code value="car_code" />`

`<input type=checkbox name=vehicle value="car" />`

I want to be able to check car and get car_code submitted also. and same for cycle

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpServletRequest` maps parameters like so: `Map<String,String[]>`

HTML form fields values are stored as a `String` array. If there's only one value, it is just an array of one `String`. In your case, you should have an array that looks  something like this:

```
String[] param = request.getParameter("code");
param[0] => "cycle_code"
param[1] => "car_code"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to dynamically set the value of the hidden field.